# How to stop an application from being launched from notification panel when any button clicked on it?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I have a notification panel with two buttons. When I click on either of the buttons the minimized application is getting opened/resumed.

```
  public void setListeners(RemoteViews view){
    Intent stopNotify = new Intent(parent,HelperActivity.class);
    stopNotify.putExtra("DO", "stop");
    PendingIntent btn1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(parent, 0, stopNotify, 0);
    view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notifyStopButton, btn1); 

    Intent pauseUpload = new Intent(parent,HelperActivity.class);
    pauseUpload.putExtra("DO", "pause");    
    PendingIntent btn2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(parent, 1, pauseUpload, 0);
    view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.uploadPauseButton, btn2); 
   }
```

I want the application to be stayed minimized itself. Am I missing something?

Do I need to add pass any parameter for pendingIntent?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

> I want the application to be stayed minimized itself. Am I missing something?

You are providing `PendingIntents` to those views that will start an activity when those views are clicked.

If you do not want this, do not provide `PendingIntents` that will start an activity.